# Custom CKEditor buttons or wrong way?

Tags: wysiwyg

I need to setup a textarea field which will provide game cheats. So I have small gifs of each and every button of Xbox, PLaystation and so on. So when someone wants to publish a cheat for Xbox he needs to insert this small gifs into the text area field. How could I go about this?
I thought it would be possible to setup a custom button for each gif in the ckeditor but I can not find out how to do it. Or is there a better way?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Option might be [BUEditor](http://drupal.org/project/bueditor) if you're not tied to CKEditor. [BUEditor](http://drupal.org/project/bueditor) buttons are [easily](http://ufku.com/drupal/bueditor/buttons) and [highly](http://ufku.com/drupal/bueditor/contributions/text-color) customizable.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was searching for, thanks a lot!